# Form param for objects

Tags: forms, coldfusion, object

I have taken over a legacy site, and my spidey sense code smell is going crazy over the form paramming used throughout the site.

For example we have a form that allows you to add a new contact, or edit an existing one dependant on the iContactId being present in the URL. So the code in the top part of the cfm file is.

```
<cfparam name="form.name" default="">
<cfparam name="form.age" default="">
<cfparam name="form.surname" default="">
<--- More cfparams for every form field--->

<cfif isDefined("URL.iContactId")>
 <cfset VARIABLES.contact = contactService.getContact("URL.iContactId")/>
   <cfset FORM.name = contact.getName() />
   <cfset FORM.age= contact.getAge() />
   <cfset FORM.surname = contact.getSurname() />
 </cfif>
```

So essentially we are defaulting all form fields to be empty and then populating them if the iContactId is in the URL. The form at the bottom part of the cfm file uses these variables like this.

```
<form>
  <input name="name" value="#FORM.name#">
```

Now, for me, the issue with these technique, is that there are around 30 form fields on this page, so I am parramming all form fields, and then setting 30 form fields to the contact objects values if the URL.iContactId variable exists. Am trying to think of a way to remove this duplication - maybe by mapping the form directly to the object?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see why not.

Get getContact() to return an "empty" object for contact ID 0 and populate the form from the empty contact object. By "empty" I mean an object with default values set for each field.

eg.

```
if (!StructKeyExists(URL,"iContactID")) URL.iContactID = 0;
variables.contact = contactService.getContact(URL.iContactID);
```

and then in the form.

```
<input name="name" value="#contact.getName()#">
```

Only thing to be aware of;  If you are doing server-side validation that returns you to this form then you will need to manage making sure that you have a contact object with the valid data in it to populate your form, so that the invalid fields can be corrected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. Yeah seems like a much better method. However, what if I had to param a form field to something specific, when URL.iContactId doesnt exist. For example, form.userSmokes = 0. As an empty contact object wouldnt provide this functionality.

Comment: Two things: 1. I'd probably use <cfparam name="URL.iContactID" value="0"> to default the ID; and 2. set up your getContact() method to return an empty object with all your defaults already set.

Comment: so have getContact() return a specified object? maybe a subclassed contact object?

Comment: This may run into problems if validation fails, and the form is redisplayed.

Comment: @sebduggan personally I prefer structKeyExists method to cfparam, but that's just personal preference. Thank you for clarifying my point of an empty object actually containing default values.